# Google Cloud "could not create Compute Engine instance without a base image" for TPU Instance

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I tries to create a TPU instance with:

> ctpu up --tf-version=1.15 --name=test --tpu-size=v2-8 --preemptible

But it says "could not create Compute Engine instance without a base image".

It was working 1 month ago, but it is not now.

Could anybody tell me what happened?

Comment: In this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/179915770) the Google TPU team will provide an update about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference posting zcain@'s response here:

> Hello, sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> As of this week, all versions <= TF-1.15.2 are deprecated.
>
> Could you try --tf-version=1.15.4 or --tf-version=1.15.5
>
> 1.15.3 is technically possible too but I wouldn't recommend it as that is also going to be deprecated soon.
>
> this page lists some versions if you ever run into this again